# bash to watch file count of multiple directories

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, syntax

I want to watch the file count of a few directories and decided to write script that repeats the same command with a one sec interval.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while:
do
    ZERO="$(ls /home/user/main | wc -l)"
    ONE="$(ls /home/user/sub/one | wc -l)"
    TWO="$(ls /home/user/sub/two | wc -l)"
    THREE="$(ls /home/user/sub/three | wc -l)"
    FOUR="$(ls /home/user/sub/four| wc -l)"
    TOTAL=$(( $ZERO + $ONE + $TWO + $THREE + $FOUR ))
    echo Total :  [ 0: $ZERO ; 1: $ONE ;  2: $TWO ; 3: $THREE ;  4: $FOUR ]
    sleep 1
done
```

But I keep getting errors like `not found while`, `Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")` or

```
: not found: watch.sh: while:
: not found: watch.sh: do
hi
: not found: watch.sh: done
```

I am entirely sure if my usage of executing commands and variables are correct. I want to store the resultant number of each command into the variable and display them in a single `echo`.

Is the loop wrong? Should I use semicolon at the end? What am I missing?

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I'm not sure what distribution/version of Linux you are running, but you should look into something like `inotifywait`, which my distro (Linux Mint) offers as part of `inotify-tools`.

Comment: You need a space between "while" and ":". The ":" is a command, it's not part of syntax.